# Getting an error when trying to create a new project in the QNX Momentics IDE (an Eclipse IDE)

Tags: eclipse, ide, qnx, blackberry-cascades

I'm attempting to create a new Blackberry Cascades C++ Project in the QNX Momentics IDE, and I was previously able to do this, but now when I attempt to do that, I get an error message dialog box up that says, "com.qnx.tools.bbt.appdescriptor.Configuration.getId()java/lang/String"

I closed everything on my computer, and restarted it, and tried again, but I still get that error.

I was able to create new projects before.

This started happening after I tried to rename a project, but a got another error popup that said, "Resource 'MyProject' is out of sync with file system", and I restarted the QNX Momentics IDE, so I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

I even tried creating a new Blackberry Cascades project in a workspace where I already created a lot of other Blackberry Cascades projects, and I got the same error.  What's going on with this?  How can I fix this?  Will I need to reinstall QNX Momentics IDE?  Or is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

It is good to uninstall previous NDKs and then install BlackBerry Gold NDK. This issue is caused by very old IDE plugins trying to interact with each other. Please make a full install of GOLD before then run update.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the solution. Just uninstall the SDK, reinstall, and that's all. The uninstaller.app is inside: /Applications/bbndk/install/

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same. I tried to uninstall it and then reinstall the NDK. Currently, it works, but maybe the problem can persist in the future.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. This problem was addressed and should no longer be present.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem after updating from an old version to the new Gold SDK's. Uninstalling and then reinstalling did the trick for me.